# Display forms choice in template-Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

On the template, when I call person.health_issue, I am getting '1','2' instead of 'Abdominal pain','Anaphylaxis'. How to display the value ('Abdominal pain','Anaphylaxis') instead of the code(1 or2 etc).

I tried with this also `{{ person.get_health_issue_display }}` in template,it is not displayed anything.

forms.py

```
   HEALTH_USSUES = (
        ('1', 'Abdominal pain'), ('2', 'Anaphylaxis'), ('3', 'Asthma'),
        ('4', 'Bruising'), ('5', 'Chest pains'), ('6', 'Coughs or Colds')
    )
    class PersonActionsForm(forms.ModelForm):

        action = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), choices=HEALTH_USSUES, required=False)
```

models.py

```
class ReportPerson(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100)
    first_aid = models.BooleanField('First aid', default=False)
    health_issue = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
def report_template(request):
     """"""
    person = ReportPerson.objects.get(pk=person_id)
    """"""
     return render(request, 'event/print.html',
             {
              'person':person
             })
```

can any one tell me how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Change 1 to `Abdominal Pain`, etc. Django will understand which tuple you are referring to

Comment: In database the field is Integer,so i am trying to do it in that way.

Comment: Show your `get_health_issue_display` mehtod?

Comment: @AamirAdnan,sorry i had not written any method for get_health_issue_display.

Comment: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/nov/02/handle-choices-right-way/ Check this link

Comment: @karthikr,finally i imported the choices in models and called the {{person.get_health_issue_display}} in template."get_health_issue_display" method not overridden

Comment: @karthikr,I gone through that link...it is given as you said...but i solved my problem with the below answer.Thanks for you reply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't have any choices set in model field `health_issue` you need to write the `get_health_issue_display` method by your self i will name it as `health_issue_display` so that default `get_FOO_display` method not gets overridden:

```
HEALTH_USSUES = (
    (1, 'Abdominal pain'), (2, 'Anaphylaxis'), (3, 'Asthma'),
    (4, 'Bruising'), (5, 'Chest pains'), (6, 'Coughs or Colds')
)

class ReportPerson(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100)
    first_aid = models.BooleanField('First aid', default=False)
    health_issue = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def health_issue_display(self):
        for c in HEALTH_USSUES:
            if c[0] == self.health_issue:
                return c[1]
```

Or just add choices in the model field:

```
health_issue = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=HEALTH_USSUES)
```

Now you have `get_health_issue_display`.

- Also make the first value in every choice as integer `(1, 'Abdominal pain')` rather than string `'1'`. Just to remove the confusion.
- You have `default=0` which does not exists in choices. Change it to `default=1`

Comment: @user2086641 you have no choices set in model. That is why `get_health_issue_display` is not available to you. You need to write it by yourself. or set the choices on model field also.

Comment: I tried the above code,my template looks like this {{ person.get_health_issue_display }},it is not showing the value,so do i need to add any other function here.

Comment: Maybe its because the default value you set is `0` which does not exists in choices. Please double check.

Comment: @user2086641 i have made some updates in the answer. Make sure you follow them.

Comment: Adhan,If i shift the form choices to models and with out "get_health_issue_display" method,it is working.But without importing the choices in models with even using this "get_health_issue_display" method not working.Can you guide me in making the choices in forms.py with this method "get_health_issue_display"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31776/discussion-between-user2086641-and-aamir-adnan)

Comment: `get_health_issue_display` is the default `get_FOO_display` method. It should not be overridden

Comment: @karthikr Thanks for this tip. But as the user was not using any choices on the model field it would not hurt so much. Anyhow changing the name of method.